# Deploy "Rename Tabs and Labels" Object

Tags: deployment, data-loader, eclipse, ant, label

I have seen a few stories touching on this topic but all I have found so far are for creating packages, not deployment from org to org.

My question is simple - is there a way (either through data or metadata deployments) to deploy the settings stored in "Rename Tabs and Labels" found under the "Customize" header in "Setup"?

It is annoying going from org to org and updating these, and I was wondering if there was a way (other then refreshing) to load these through e.g. Data Loader or ANT/Eclipse?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These settings are stored in the [CustomObjectTranslation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm) metadata object, and you can deploy them in any tool that uses the metadata API.  (You can make this change by using the metadata APIs either using ANT and manually building a package.xml, or by writing a custom script to do it using SOAP.)

---

You can also use [Gearset](https://gearset.com) to make this change*. To do this using Gearset:

1. Visit https://gearset.com and click `Try it now`
2. Enter source org details that has the renamed tab
3. Enter target org details that you want to move the change to
4. Run comparison
5. Filter to find 'CustomObjectTranslation'
6. Select the ones you want to deploy and we build an additive package so you don't lose changes in the target org
7. Press `Deploy` and let us do the hard work

We want to make Salesforce deployment and moving things from org to org really simple. Any feedback you can give us is really appreciated.

[image: This is what the difference looks like]
[image: This is what the summary screen looks like]

*Full disclosure that I am one of the team behind Gearset, and there are other ways to do this without using our tool. We just hope to make it easy for you* :)

Comment: Thanks - I am already familiar with ANT but never knew of this metadata type. Thanks very much for the detailed explanation I appreciate it.

Comment: Interesting. Is this doable with the standard force.com migration tool?

Comment: To my understanding no - the standard salesforce packaging tool uses limited metadata APIs and also struggles with deploying permissions unless you deploy profiles with every package. I strongly recommend ANT or Eclipse to surpass these issues.

Comment: I'm not sure @mkorman. We use the same APIs that the Force.com Migration Tool (ANT) uses. We do process the XML from the package heavily to allow things like partial component deploys, and selective deploying of metadata components., but it is all possibly manually if you have the patience :)